# Enviar datos de formulario mediante ajax a API-REST en node js

Tags: javascript, html5, ajax

Estoy tratando de enviar datos desde un formulario mediante ajax a una apiRest hecho en nodejs, al enviar me sale errores, quiza este haciendo algo mal en mi código `ajax`. El formulario es el siguiente:

```
<div class="container">
    <br>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col s12 m9">
            <div class="card-panel">
                <h5 class="center">REGISTRO</h5>
                <div class="divider"></div><br>
                <div class="row">

                    <form method="post" id="register" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="s12">
                        <div class="input-field col s12 m6">
                            <input placeholder="Nombres" name="name" id="name" type="text" required>
                            <label for="first_name">NOMBRES</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-field col s12 m6">
                            <input placeholder="Email" name="email" id="email" type="text" required>
                            <label for="email">EMAIL</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-field col s12 m6">
                            <input placeholder="Contraseña" name="password" id="password" type="password" required>
                            <label for="celular">CONTRASEÑA</label>
                        </div>
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Fotografia frontal:</td>
                                <td><input type="file" name="image" id="image" required></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Fotografia frontal:</td>
                                <td><input type="file" name="image2" id="image" required></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>

                        <div class="col s12">
                            <div class="divider"></div><br>
                            <div class="center">
                                <input class="btn black" type="submit" value="REGISTRAR CONDUCTOR">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/register.js" ></script>
```

Mediante el código siguiente de `ajax` quiero enviar los datos tanto como texto e imagen a la `api`:

```
$("#register").on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var f = $(this);

    var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("register"));
    $.ajax({
        url: "url de la api",
        type: "post",
        dataType: "json",
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        proccessData: false,
    })
    .done(function(res){
        console.log("Archivo enviado");
    });

});
```

Pero al tratar de enviar me sale errores... Quizá este haciendo algo mal en el código, soy nuevo en programación.

Comment: El `id` de tu `<form>` es `register_driver`, no solamente `register`, empieza por cambiar eso en `$("#register").on('submit', function(e){...` y en `var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("register"));` y comenta que otros errores aparecen.

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation`,
    `at i (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2)`,
    `at qt (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2)`,
    `at Function.k.param (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2)`,
    `at Function.ajax (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2)`,
    `at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (register.js:12)`,
    `at HTMLFormElement.dispatch (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2)`,
    `at HTMLFormElement.v.handle (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2)`, la linea 12 empieza el `ajax`

Comment: Esos son los errores que me muestra al dar click en registrar

Comment: al parecer es un error en el src de jquery, sustitúyelo por esto `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` y comenta que sucede.

Comment: Me mustra el mismo error, o quiza este haciendo algo mal en el ajax

Comment: tienes una ultima coma en `processData: false,` bórrala ya que el ajax de jquery se maneja como estructura de json. Debería quedar así 

`$.ajax({
        url: "url de la api",
        type: "post",
        dataType: "json",
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        proccessData: false
    })
    .done(function(res){
        console.log("Archivo enviado");
    });

});`

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que obtener el primer elemento de tu form data que en este caso sera tu formulario

```
var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("register")[0]);
```

Y tienes mal escrita la linea:

```
  proccessData: false,
```

cambiala por esta:

```
    processData: false,
```